# Internet recovery mode macos not working

Tags: macos, mac

I have dual boot with windows and recently my macos stopped working but windows still works perfectly, so I was trying to use internet recovery mode but after de internet loading finishes, it starts the apple loading screen wich stops at the middle. I don’t know what else to do

Comment: What prompted macOS to stop working? Did you do anything to the disk partitioning from within Windows?

Comment: The only thing i did unsual from the windows was using a command in the windows power shell to enable the execution of power scripts for using node and after using it I disabled it

Comment: so what exactly "doesn't work"? You've really given us almost nothing to go on. What OS? What does it look like if you hold Opt at boot? What happens when you do try to boot to macOS? The more detail you give, the closer people can get to the right answer.

Comment: I have os catalina and when i boot the catalina partition it stops working on apple logo loading page and it doesn’t let me enter the recovery mode. The windows partition was working perfectly until i used internet recovery mode that also stopped on apple logo loading

Comment: My first guess is that the internet connection isn't working. Do you have ethernet you can connect instead of Wi-Fi? I'd assume you'll need a USB/thunderbolt dongle too.

Comment: I do, i can try it but i also tried with a bootable usb wich doenst need internet and it also got stuck

Comment: I tried with a ethernet cable and still got stuck